# Max count() for every group of GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get max(Option) for each group made of group by function.

Suppose we have:

```
Name:      Option: 
Name1      o1
Name1      o2
Name1      o1
Name1      o1
Name1      o3
Name2      o4
Name2      o5
Name2      o4
Name3      o6
Name3      o7
Name3      o7
Name3      o8
```

The final result is expected to be:

```
Group:     max count of option:
Name1      o1
Name2      o4
Name3      o7
```

Comment: Can you get the count of option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the option counts, you can do:

```
select `group`, `option`, count(*) as cnt
from table t
group by `group`, `option`;
```

There are several ways to get the option corresponding to the maximum value.  I think the easiest in this case is the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` method:

```
select `group`,
       substring_index(group_concat(`option` order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as maxoption
from (select `group`, `option`, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by `group`, `option`
     ) tgo
group by `group`;
```

Comment: Thank you. The second query did the job. The first query give the number of the grouped options for every name.